# Why do the eigenvalues change from $\sin(k\pi x)$ to $2 - 2\cos(k\pi h)$ in this worked example?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> "Find the eigenvalues of the -1,2, -1 tridiagonal n by n matrix K (my
> favorite).
>
> Solution: The best way is to guess λ and x. Then check $Kx = λx$.
> Guessing could not  work for most matrices, but special cases are a
> big part of mathematics (pure and applied).  The key is hidden in a
> differential equation. The second difference matrix K is like a
> second derivative, and those eigenvalues are much easier to see:
>
> Eigenvalues $λ_1$, $λ_2$...
>
> Eigenfunctions $y_1$, $y_2$...
>
> $d^2y/dx^2= λy(x)$
>
> with
>
> $y(0) = 0$
>
> and
>
> $y(1) = 0 $
>
> Try $y = \sin(cx)$. Its second derivative is $y'' = -c^2 sin(cx)$. So the
> eigenvalue will be  $λ = -c^2$, provided $y(x)$ satisfies the end
> point conditions $y(0) = 0 = y(1)$.  Certainly $sin 0 = 0$ (this is
> where cosines are eliminated by $cos(0) = 1$). At $x = 1$,  we need
> $y(1) = sin( c) = 0$. The number $c$ must be $kπ$, a multiple of $π$ , and
> $λ$ is $-c^2 $:
>
> Eigenvalues $λ=-k^2π^2$
>
> Eigenfunctions $y=sin(kπx)$
>
> Now we go back to the matrix K and guess its eigenvectors. They come
> from $sinkπx$ at n points $x = h, 2h, ... ,nh$, equally spaced between
> 0 and 1. The spacing $Δx$ is $h =  1/(n + 1)$, so the $(n + 1)$st
> point comes out at $(n + 1)h = 1$. Multiply that sine vector S  by K:
>
> Eigenvector of K = sine vector s
>
> $Ks = λs = (2 - 2cos(kπh)) s $
>
> $s = (sin( kπh),... , sin( nkπh))$.
>
> I will leave that multiplication $Ks = λs$
> as a challenge problem.
> Notice what is important:
>
> 1. All eigenvalues $2 - 2 cos( kπh)$ are positive and K is positive definite.
> 2. The sine matrix S has orthogonal columns = eigenvectors $s_1 , ... , s_n$ of K."

I don't understand why he says the eigenvalues are

$λ=-k^2π^2$

and then he says they are an apparently a different value

$2 - 2 cos (kπ h)$

Could someone please explain

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take the time to format math formulas properly - [see here for documentation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've done some of the work on formatting your question a bit better, do you think you could look at what I did and then try to complete the rest using that as an example?

Comment: Thanks, hope I was able to improve my formatting somewhat

Answer (score 1):

The "he" (instructor, author, etc. referred to by the OP) considers two different problems: A. a continuous one from differential equation and B. the matrix problem from the task. They are related, "he" claims, by B being the discretization of A. Therefore the eigenvector of B is expected to be a discretization of A.

"He" expects the solution to A being more accessible to "his" audience and solves A first. Then "he" guesses a candidate for the eigenvector of B from the eigenvector of A. It turns out, that this works for the eigenvectors, however the eigenvalues for A and B turn out to be quite different - however see the comment of **Ian** for some relation. That is not a problem, as the link between A and B was not expected to come from eigenvalues but from eigemvectors and that worked out.

Comment: The eigenvalues are also related, it is just that this $K$ needs to be multiplied by $-1/h^2$ in order to behave like the second derivative as $h \to 0$. Once you do that you see that these are equal to within leading order in $h$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments